# Runtime error after installing Django cms

Tags: python, django, django-cms, flutterwave

I was in the process of doing a pip install to integrate payments to my Django website. When I run migrations I had gotten a module error that stated that Django cms could not be found. I fixed the problem by running `pip install djangocms-installer`

I then receive this error when running migrations.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\rahisi-ecom\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\payrave\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cms.models import CMSPlugin
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cms\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pagemodel import *  # nopyflakes
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cms\models\pagemodel.py", line 1626, in <module>
    class PageType(Page):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class cms.models.pagemodel.PageType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

My Installed Apps is as follows.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_countries',
    'payrave',
    'core',
    'menus', 
]
```

Comment: What is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: @rob I have edited the question to display installed apps